# Why is this callback handler being called twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following JavaScript code. When the user clicks a button on the page, it reads the "name" and "stepId" from data attributes, and then opens a Twitter bootstrap modal dialog. When the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button is clicked on the dialog, it fires the supplied callback.

This works great the first time it is invoked. The problem is that on all subsequent invocations, when clicking the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button, the callback is fired twice. On the first callback we see the `stepId` from the first invocation, and on the second callback we see the `stepId` from the current invocation.

`clearInputTargetName` and `clearInputName` are always the correct value in the dialog.

```
var Dialog = function (dlgId)
{
   var okCallback = null;

   var show = function (cb)
   {
      okCallback = cb;

      jQuery.noConflict();
      $(dlgId).modal("show");
   };

   var hide = function ()
   {
      jQuery.noConflict();
      $(dlgId).modal("hide");
   };

   var onOK = function ()
   {
      okCallback();
   };

   var init = function ()
   {
      $(dlgId + " .okButton").off('click').on('click', function ()
      {
         onOK(true);
         hide();
      });
   };

   init();
   
   return {
      show: show,
      hide: hide,
      init: init
   };
};

var ClearInputDialog = function ()
{
   var show = function (input, cb)
   {
      var dlg = new Dialog("#clearInputDialog", input);

      $("#clearInputTargetName").text(input);
      $("#clearInputName").text(input);

      dlg.show(function ()
      {
         cb(true);
         dlg.hide();
      });
   };

   return { show: show };
};

var WorkflowDesignerVM = function ()
{
   var clearInput = function ()
   {
      var name = $(this).attr("data-input");
      var stepId = $(this).attr("data-stepid");

      var dlg = new ClearInputDialog();
      dlg.show(name, function (result)
      {
         alert('clearing stepId: ' + stepId);
      });
   };

   var init = function ()
   {
      $(document).on("click", ".clear-input", clearInput);
   };
   
   init();
};

var vm = new WorkflowDesignerVM();
```

And the modal dialog looks like this:

```
<div id="clearInputDialog" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Clear Input for <span id="clearInputTargetName">[clearInputTargetName]</span></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to clear <span id="clearInputName">[clearInputName]</span>?
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancelButton" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="clearInputButton" class="btn btn-primary okButton" data-stepid="" data-input="">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with my jQuery event handler code. If I change the Dialog.init to the following code, then we always get one callback, but we always see the stepId from the first invocation.

```
var init = function ()
{
   $(dlgId + " .okButton").on('click', function ()
   {
      onOK(true);
      hide();
          
      $(dlgId + " .okButton").off('click');
   });
};
```

Comment: Why are you doing `jQuery.noConflict()` many times? Did you forget to do this in `init`? Seems like a source of problems...

Comment: Honestly, I have a poor understanding of what jQuery.noConflict does. I just know that I had problems before launching a boostrap modal and the solution I was given was to call this function first. Do I only need to call it once?

Comment: @elclanrs well it turns out that was my problem. I put jQuery.noConflict in Dialog.init right before the click handler, and removed it from the other locations, and now it works as expected. If you want to make an answer for this I will accept it.

Comment: It may work for now... Typically you call it once and assign it to a variable and use that, or just call `noConflict` and then use a `document.ready` function and pass `$` as parameter. I think you're just trying to abstract too much too soon. I suggest you solve the problem in a functional step by step way first, then when everything is working abstract the selectors and the events.

Comment: Well, that's kinda what I did. I had this working correctly in a simple but ugly functional layout, but since I have about 40 different dialogs I wanted to abstract it out to make it cleaner and couldn't figure out why this error was happening. I guess I shouldn't be using noConflict without having any idea what it actually does. I will be looking it up now.

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict()` is used when you have other libraries (or your own JS) that assigns to `$`. If you have no conflict, you don't need it. Usually you use `jQuery.noConflict()` exactly once on page load.

Comment: I tried calling it before document.ready and passing $ as a parameter, but I still had the error that modal was not a function on my bootstrap call. I put the noConflict call inside of the document.ready handler, and it appears to be working. I still can't say I understand why it's working that way and not the other or what the best way to use it in my scenario is, so I'll probably make another question about that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding event stop propagation within your click function, as well as, add return false.  This will stop any event propagation or double invocations.  Also, rather than using off().on()... try just .live() and then, use off() when you are ready to remove the click event when the click is not available for the user, as well as, remove it from memory.

```
$(dlgId + " .okButton").live('click', function (event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
  event = null;
  onOK(true);
  hide();
  return false;
});
```